# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n\pi/3)}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ converges/diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ converge, converge absolutely or diverge?

I am again lost with a series.  With Dirichlet's test I came to the conclusion that it converges. But I don't know how to show that it doesn't converge absolutely. Any ideas?

Comment: Does there exist a subsequence that does not converge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $$n\gt 1 \Rightarrow n > \sqrt n  \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{\sqrt n} >\frac1n$$

Now use the harmonic series.

**Edit**: I don't really know what you intend with considering $\sin^2(\cdots)$. It's much simpler than that. The idea is that there's subsequences where the term is a constant divided by $\sqrt n$ (the same constant for each term). For example take the series (which is "contained" in your series) $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{(6k+1)\pi}{3}}{\sqrt{6k+2}} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}})}{\sqrt{6k+2}} = \sin(\pi/3)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{6k+2}}$$
which diverges by the first hint. Since the original series in absolute value is non-negative and greater than or equal to the above series, it too is divergent.

Comment: I am not sure that I get you - did you mean this?:$\sum{\frac{|sin\frac{n\pi}{3}|}{\sqrt{n+1}}}>\sum{\frac{|sin\frac{n\pi}{3}|}{n}}$? May be yes, then I could do $\sum{\frac{|sin\frac{n\pi}{3}|}{n}}\geq\sum{\frac{sin^2\frac{n\pi}{3}}{n}}=\sum{\frac{1-cos^2\frac{n\pi}{3}}{n}}=\sum{\frac{1}{n}}-\sum{\frac{cos^2\frac{n\pi}{3}}{n}}$. And if I am not mistaken, then $\sum{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges and the second one converges so my first sum must diverge?

Comment: whether this will give the solution?? If, so explain

Comment: $|\sin \frac {n\pi} 3|<1$ which gives $|\sin \frac {n\pi} 3|<\sin^2 \frac {n\pi} 3$

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then yours gives this solution $|sin\frac{n\pi}{3}|\leq 1$ therefore $sin^2\frac{n\pi}{3}\leq|sin\frac{n\pi}{3}|$

Comment: @GorteX I've expanded a bit.

Comment: Thanks, it´s much clearer now...

Comment: @GorteX There's a slight detail omitted that I should mention: The hint I give in the beginning proves that $1/\sqrt{6k+2} > 1/(6k+2)$. This isn't the full harmonic series though. You should probably prove that it (the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6k+2}$) also diverges.

Comment: @GPerez But that is quite easy yet - to come up with the idea of subsequence is much harder. I am in my first year at university and some solutions just doesn't pop up :)

Comment: @GorteX I just didn't want to leave an incomplete proof. As to how it "popped up", I just noticed that $\sin(n\pi/3)$ goes through three values repeatedly, and thought of how to vary $n$ so I could make it "skip" two of them. Good luck with your university!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sin\frac{n\pi}3=\begin{cases}\;\;\;\frac{\sqrt3}2&,\;\;n=1,2\pmod 6\\{}\\\;\;\;\;\;0&,\;\;n=0,3\pmod 6\\{}\\-\frac{\sqrt3}2&,\;\;n=4,5\pmod 6\end{cases}\implies\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right|=0\,,\;\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

From here that

$$s_{3k}=\sum_{n=1}^{3k}\left|\frac{\sin{\frac{n\pi}3}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right|=\frac{\sqrt3}2\left(\frac1{\sqrt1}+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt4}+\frac1{\sqrt5}+\ldots+\frac1{\sqrt{3k-2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{3k-1}}\right)\ge$$

$$\ge\frac{\sqrt3}2\cdot\frac{2k}{\sqrt{3k-1}}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Thus the sequence of partial sums of the absolute values of the series isn't bounded above and thus the series diverges.